# Why function call inside arrow function passed to a onClick in react is not working?

Tags: reactjs

I am have a material-ui component AppBar (using hooks) and i have to toggle the drawer (class based component) and i have a reference to function toggleDrawer in AppBar.js using props.toggleDrawer.

---

I want to call the function when a user clicks on the IconButton component in AppBar so i tried to give the onClick attribute to that component with a arrow fuction having a call to toggleDrawer(), but it is not working i have to call the function directly from the onClick attribute in order to work. Why is it so, according to my knowledge we should be passing the arrow function in order to avoid the call to that function during parsing JSX to vanilla js.

```
<IconButton
            onClick = { props.toggleDrawer('left', true) }
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
          >
          <MenuIcon />
</IconButton>
```

This above code is working but below is not. :(

```
<IconButton
            onClick = { () => { props.toggleDrawer('left', true)} }
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
          >
          <MenuIcon />
</IconButton>
```

*note: I don't have knowledge about hooks but the AppBar component which is having the IconButton component is using hooks can it cause this issue.

Comment: Remove the curly braces: onClick = { ()=> props.toggleDrawer(‘left’, true) }

Comment: This won't change anything

Answer (score 0):

If you were referring to this example [drawer](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/). Then `toggleDrawer` is a curried function (a function returning another function when called ones). `toggleDrawer` is already returning a function which will be invoked onClick. But when you put it inside an arrow function, then there is no function invocation happening. When `toggleDrawer` is called with `side` and `open`, it returns another function, that takes `event` and returns `void`. Check below.

```
const toggleDrawer = (side: DrawerSide, open: boolean) => (
    event: React.KeyboardEvent | React.MouseEvent,
  ) => {
    if (
      event.type === 'keydown' &&
      ((event as React.KeyboardEvent).key === 'Tab' ||
        (event as React.KeyboardEvent).key === 'Shift')
    ) {
      return;
    }

    setState({ ...state, [side]: open });
  };
```